# slideUp related UI design

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

I am working on a UI concept which is visible here http://jsfiddle.net/nudeape/CZsjw/1/

I want that when I click 'more' the extra text shall slide up and the overall height of the super-container (li.update) shall increase accordingly. The base of li.update shall remain as it is, and its top edge shall slide up overlapping the 'Heading' text and the line above it.

Can somebody please help me??

Answer (score 0):

Very nice idea. You just had a very simple problem.

Your css has a small error.

If you change this:

```
.update ul.expand{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

to this:

```
​.update ul.expand{
    display:none;
}
```

It works great!

Here is the fixed jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CZsjw/11/

Comment: actually.. what I want is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nudeape/CZsjw/2/